# Ask for a good reference for the calculus involving singular continuous measure

Tags: probability-theory, functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory

I am not an expert on measure theory. I am sorry if this question is too simple for some experts here.

Suppose the measure $\mu$ is singular continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, such as the cantor measure. Are there good references about the calculus with respect this measure?

Here is one concrete question. Let $\mu$ be the Cantor measure, what is a general procedure to evaluate

$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\mu(d x) =?
$$

for some continuous  function $f(x)$. For some specific functions, such as $f(x)=x$, $f(x)=1-x$, $f(x)=1$, one can use integration by parts and symmetry to solve this problem. How about for general continuous function $f$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What on earth is the stochastic-calculus tag doing here?

Comment: @YemonChoi: I removed it.  I also voted to migrate to Math.SE since I think it is a better fit there.

Comment: Yemon Choi, people working on stochastic calculus might have this knowledge as well.

Comment: Nate Eldredge, may I know what is Math.SE? Thanks.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, okay, thanks. :)

Comment: Anand, just because people working on X might know how to answer your question, it doesn't mean your question belongs under that tag.

Comment: I see, Thanks Yemon Choi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical way to integrate continuous functions against complicated measures is to approximate them (in the weak topology) by simpler measures.

One approach for the Cantor measure is to follow the middle-thirds construction, where you write the Cantor set as a decreasing intersections of sets $C_n$ each of which is a finite union of closed intervals.  If $\mu_n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $C_n$, normalized so that $\mu_n(C_n)=1$, then $\mu$ is the weak limit of the $\mu_n$.  So you can say $$\int f\,d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{m(C_n)} \int_{C_n} f\,dm.$$
You could also approximate by discrete measures: let $B_n$ be the finite set consisting of the endpoints of the $2^n$ intervals remaining after the $n$th stage of the construction (so $|B| = 2^{n+1}$).  Normalized counting measure on $B_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$, i.e. 
$$\int f\,d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{-(n+1)} \sum_{x \in B_n} f(x).$$

Comment: Thanks Nate Eldredge for your help! Do you have a reference for this so that I can learn it more systematically? In my problem, I have a general singular continuous measure, not necessary the Cantor measure. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anand: Weak convergence of measures is covered in most probability texts, but the canonical introduction is Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures*.

Comment: thanks a lot! I agree. But all information that I know about my measure $\mu$ is that it is a singular continuous (nonnegative) measure. In this setting, do you have any idea to construct a sequence of measures $\mu_n$ that converge to $\mu$ in the weak sense? Is there a general construction procedure? Thank you very much!

Comment: To get an effective approximation strategy, you need to know something about the measure you're using and its properties.  Asking "how do I integrate against a general measure" is like asking "how do I find the cardinality of a set" - strategies for finding the cardinality of $\{1,2\} \cup \{2,3,4\}$ will be much different from those for finding the cardinality of $\aleph_{\aleph_5}^{\aleph_6}$.  It would help to know what kind of results you're trying to prove.

Comment: I agree. According to the Lebesgue's decomposition theorem, $\mu$ has three parts. I study them separately. The absolutely continuous part is easy; the pure jump part reduces to the study of the Dirac delta measure. The problem arises if the singular continuous part is not vanishing, I need to prove something. Thanks a lot!