# Distribution of random variable for which density parameter is another random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Say $X$ is a random variable that has a density $f_p$ depending on a parameter $p$ (for instance the parameter for a normal random variable would be the mean an variance or for a Bernoulli the probability of success, ect...). Now say that $p$ is also a random variable in the problem, call it $P$. Now given a set $A$, how can I express $\mathbb{P}(X\in A)$ depending on the the density $f_p$ and also using the distribution of $P$ (call it $\mu_P$)? I think this has maybe something to do with mixture models.

Comment: I think what you mean is that the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $P=p$ has density $f_p$. For calculating $\mathbb{P}(X\in A)$, you then need to use the law of total probability.

Comment: $$\mathbb P(X\in A)=\int \int_A f_p(x)\,dx P(dp)$$

Comment: @Snildt, thank you. Could you write the relation you mention in maths? Also I cannot find the law of total probability when $P$ is a generic mesure on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), neither in the book I have. Its application should give the result of Andrew but what is the generic formula? Do you have a reference for this law of total probability?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called a [compound distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution).

Given a set $A$ we can get $P(X \in A)$ by integrating over the conditional density. Let $P \sim g(p)$:

$$P(X \in A) = \int_{p \in \Omega_p}\int_A g(p)f_p(x)dxdp$$

Where $\Omega_p$ is just the range of $P$.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that a mixture distribution is also called a compound distribution. I wanted to treat the case where $P$ is not absolutely continuous

Comment: @edamondo even if g(p) is discrete, then this is just a mixture. If $g(p)$ is singular, there are ways to complete the integral (see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934789/ask-for-a-good-reference-for-the-calculus-involving-singular-continuous-measure)

Answer (score 1):

You have to be precise about what you mean by $X$ has a density that depends on random parameter $P$. You could formulate this mathematically as asserting that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $P = p$ has density $f_p$. This means you want a joint distribution $(P, X)$ where $P \sim \mu_P$ and $P(X \in dx \mid P = p) = f_p(x)\,dx$. Such a joint distribution exists, and can be defined in a natural way by
$$P((P, X) \in S) = \int \mu_P(dp) \int f_p(x)\,dx \, 1_{S}(p,x).$$
You can define arbitrary joint distributions with desired conditional distributions in this way, as a composition of transition kernels.

Comment: Kakashi sensei, what does the notation $P(X\in dx|P=p)$ exactly means?

Comment: @edamondo It is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $P = p$. Some books use $d\mu(x)$ to mean the same as $\mu(dx)$.